# ECONNREFUSED Error when trying to run Firebase pubsub scheduled cloud function on shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to run a pubsub.schedule function on Firebase emulator. I tried to follow the instructions in the following links.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1748#issuecomment-609735979

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#set_up_admin_credentials_optional

I keep  getting the error below when I run `firebase functions:shell`.

`Error: Server Error. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4400`

Any idea how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: I deleted the whole project and started from scratch. I didn't get the error again. It can be a setup issue.

Comment: It worked again after i restarted the console

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to run `firebase emulators:start` before `firebase functions:shell`.  Doing that first worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this was caused by Microsoft Defender, it may be any other firewall block.
Try running "firebase emulators:start" in the same cmd window, if you get a message from MS Defender, click "Allow". Then you can stop the emulators and run "firebase functions:shell" in the same cmd window, it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after running "firebase emulators:start" everything worked. It appeared that the command installed a few .jar files and perhaps that was the reason.